# calling method before declaration in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

how can I call a function which it`s declaration is after method call in angularJs?

```
$scope.x();
$scope.x = function(){
    console.log("calling method");
  }
```

Comment: i would like to understand why you need it in first place, tough using timeout u can achieve it.

Comment: I have different server requests, so I want to send request whenever each method is called . Actually I want to add Lazy Loading.

Comment: I have a base page and there are different tabs on it. I want to Call each method on click of It`s tab. So I call the method on Base page but method declaration is in Another AngularJs controller.(all of are in one state)

Comment: @YyAaSs Did my answer work for you ?

Comment: You mention a lot of different things in your comments ... to tackle LazyLoading I recommend using [ui-router's implementation](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/lazyloading). As for controller-to-controller communication architecture, I'd recommend an event-driven approach using $scope.$broadcast and $scope.$on

Comment: Regarding your initial question, you could define an init function and call it after all the other function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
$scope.x = abc;
$scope.x();
function abc(){
    console.log("calling method");
}
```

Note: In case you want to give `abc` function the same name `x`, it will also be possible.

Comment: No again the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this if you want to call abc function on x model.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

function abc(){
    console.log("calling method");
  }
$scope.x = abc();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```